# “We three” vs “us three”

Tags: word-usage, personal-pronouns, subject-or-object

In the sentence,

> *"We three will go to the Express mall. You can find **we/us** three there, having a good time."*

I'm unsure whether to use *we/us* for the second reference.

I have read about *we* and *us* usage with respect to the subjective and objective pronouns and also about usage with finite verb and infinite verbs.

Comment: The personal determinative "we" is correct.

Comment: Can you tell which is correct: "You can find I there", "You can find me there".  The difference we/us and he/him and she/her is the same.

Comment: @BillJ I know which one I prefer between: "*You can find we there.*" and "*You can find us there.*"

Comment: @GEdgarg you're forgetting that "we" is a personal determinative here, not a pronoun. "We teachers are going on strike" is infinitively preferable to "Us teachers are going on strike".

Comment: Of course, as Christmas approaches this is even more strongly influenced by "We three kings of orient are".

Comment: @BillJ no it isn't.  As to your teachers example, the determinative is the subject, so _we_ is correct.  In the question, the determinative is the object, so _us_ is correct.

Comment: @phoog The subject of my "teachers" example is the NP "we teachers", where "teachers" is head and "we" is determiner.

Answer (score 2):

"**Us** three" is correct.

In "we three" the meaning is "we, who are three in number". "Three" is used post-positionally and adjectivally (or in apposition) and does not influence the case change of "we" to "us", i.e. it does not prevent the change from the subjective "we" (nominative) to the objective "us".

1916   R. L. McCardell Diamond from Sky xxix. 423   *You may be an adopted gipsy, and Arthur may be a born one, but of us three I am the real Romany.*

Comment: Not so. "The personal determinative "we" is correct

Comment: @BillJ and you can provide reasoning, authority and examples?

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that the two of you are diametrically opposed. You are both wrong. "We" cannot be the object of the verb "find" and "us" cannot be the subject of the verb "go". You have both missed the fact that there are two sentences and the grammar requirements are different. I'll let you fight it out between you. Meanwhile I have given a comprehensive answer that covers all cases plus actual usages

Comment: The personal determinative is nominitives, "we". It has no accusative form.

Comment: @Greybeard. Thank you. So you mean when the number is positioned after the pronoun, we should use us rather than we .

Comment: @Aksp In your examples "we" is not a pronoun but a determinative.  No one would say *Us three will go to ...

Comment: @BillJ  -  I'm sorry but I hear "us two will .." and "us three will .." regularly. It is wrong but it is common.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica The OP asked  for the 'correct' form, and this is best answered by mentioning the personal determinative "we".

Comment: @BillJ  - Okay, so write an answer with supporting evidence.

Comment: @Aksp No. "three" has no real effect on "we": **we** behaves as it would if "three" were not there.

Comment: I haven't found a great number of relevant examples in a Google ngram search, but the determiner usage of 'us' in 'us three' certainly prevails _after prepositions_ ('besides us three', 'with us three', 'for us three' ...) [searches 'we/us three there'] and in DO position ('took us three there', 'That our late Prince treated us three with courtesy was because the True Way was still preserved.') [took we/us three]. It certainly sounds better than 'we' in non-subject position to my ageing ears. Though not always totally natural.  _In_ subject position ('Us three went first') it is non-standard.

Comment: @BillJ At this point your answer would be helpful.

Comment: @BillJ a web search for the phrase `"personal determinative"` does not yield anything related to English grammar.  Unless you can cite some authority to back this up I can only conclude that it is your own idiosyncratic theory.

Answer (score 1):

> we three will go to the Express mall.
>
> You can find we/us three there, having a good time"

None of this is what a 21st century native speaker is likely to say in ordinary conversation. I have given the most likely version in bold below.

In conversation, many people do not stick to any strict rules of grammar (or indeed know any rules).

If you want a rule here's a simple one.

Remove "three" from the sentences.

*We  will go to the Express mall.*  ("We" is the subject of the verb "go")+

*You can find us there, having a good time.*  ("us" is the direct object of the verb)"find")

Now replace the word "three" in those sentences and you have your answer.

---

Having said that, this is all very artificial. I can't imagine native speakers talking like that.

We might say

or

***The three of us will go to the Express mall.***  ("us" is correct because it follows "of")

***You can find us there, having a good time.*** (No need to repeat "three" because it has just been said)

If you really want to repeat "three", then we would say

*The three of us will go to the Express mall.*  (This makes "three" the subject of the sentence)

*You can find the three of us there, having a good time.*

---

Finally, in a lower register (said by people who have never learned grammar or prefer to ignore it) you will hear

"Us three will go to the Express mall" (This goes against any formal rules but is certainly a common way of speaking informally)

Comment: Your procedure results in the wrong answer in the second example, where nominative "we" is correct. "You can find we three there".

Comment: @ BillJ - I'm sorry but you are simply wrong. I think you are committing the error of hypercorrection. Not only does that sound dreadful. It abides by no known rules of grammar.

Comment: @chasly, thank you for the detailed explanation. Yes, the statement looks very artificial. But I see this  in grade 3 grammar book for the personal pronoun exercise. They have just introduced the personal and possessive pronouns but  thia particular sentence in the exercise was little complex for grade 3 kid. So just wanted to be sure which one is correct.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the personal determintive "we"?

Comment: @ BillJ  -  Let's stick to grammar. I'd be interested to see your answer with supporting evidence from authoritative sources.

Comment: Doesn't address the actual question. While idiomatic alternatives are given, that is surely ELL level.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - If you read carefully, I did answer the question. I gave a rule, i.e. remove the word "three", choose what looks right and then replace "three" afterwards. Although you may or may not agree with this answer, it is nevertheless *an* answer.

Comment: "the three of us" is not only the most natural way of saying this in informal modern English (the context in which the question is asked), it also avoids a bind where the OP might write something that would be contentious no matter which option they chose (neither "we three" nor "us three" appears to be approved by all commenters, while nobody has said "the three of us" is ungrammatical).

Comment: << We three” vs “us three”
...
In the sentence[s]

"We three will go to the Express mall. You can find we/us three there, having a good time."

I'm unsure whether to use we/us for the second reference. >> Agreed, not the idiomatic choice, but specific. I believe one is acceptable if awkward, the other wrong. But where to find a supporting reference? Hence no answer from me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The example has red herrings: At a minimum, it is **"You can find us"** with "us" as the object - ** there** is an adverb and **"having a good time"** is a participle/gerund phrase modifying "us". It is the same as "You can find us riding a horse." and you would never say "You can find *we* riding a horse."

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually give two answers to the same question but I think it is justified in this case.

There are a few questions that come up on language forums repeatedly and that are the source of battles between participants. I recall one on [Wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/forums/english-only.6/) that had over a hundred pages of argument and was never resolved to anyone's satisfaction.

In the end almost all these disagreements come down to whether one is an adherent of [prescriptive or descriptive grammar](https://pediaa.com/difference-between-descriptive-and-prescriptive-grammar/)

Prescriptive grammar tells us how we *should* write or speak whereas descriptive grammar tells us how people actually speak in real life.

**Answer**

When asking on a forum such as Stack Exchange, you will sometimes run into one of these points of contention - this is one of them.

As a result, you have to choose between what the textbook says and what actual people say. English grammar varies in different parts of the world, so it's best to choose a particular region and stick to it.

If you want to speak like a native then you do best to choose descriptive grammar. If you want to pass a test with the highest marks then you probably need to follow prescriptive rules.

So, which are the rules to follow? The only answer in my opinion, is to discover which textbook is recommended by the people who set the test and follow that.

If you are still in doubt then come back here and quote the textbook. That way we can help you understand it.

Good luck!

Comment: When people make prescriptive claims, they should always cite and link to the reference, in accordance with ELU regulations (I believe that's not too strong a term) or add a modal caveat (_IMO_, say). And not even Quirk et al is unassailable. But these are comments, not answers.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - I agree, however I make no prescriptive claims - I am a firm descriptivist!  The original question asks which is correct. My answer is neither because most people don't speak like that.  However in a comment, the OP expresses a desire to do well in a test. In that case the "correct" answer is one that the testers believe to be correct.  The best way to discover this is to find out which set of prescriptive rules they follow (if possible).